# Use of keygen tag in html5

Tags: java, html, security

As part of my application i want a secret key that should be known to the user and server before my actual process starts. I explored about `<keygen>` tag in html5.

It is said that `<keygen>` element is a key-pair generator. When a form is submitted, two keys are generated, one private and one public (the private key is stored on the client, and the public key is sent to the server).

Do we need to write any code to store the private key or will it automatically gets stored?

If the public key is sent to the server, will it be in key format or in string format (if we receive the key in key format in jsp or servlet the processing will be easier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is sent to the server as a POST/GET parameter, it is up to the server what to do with the key. Like any other POST/GET parameter, the key is sent as a string, so unless your web framework knows how to decode the POST/GET parameters into objects, the key will be in string format.

Comment: k,thank u..What about the private key that is generated at Client side.any idea??

Comment: @user1168647: I believe it will be stored by the browser automatically when the form is posted, but I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: IF the private key is stored by the browser,how can we get it??Could you(Lie Ryan) please help me out???

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the private key should never leave the computer hence there is no API to get it.
AFAIK the only way to get the private key is to make up a certificate with the public key, import it to the browser and export the certificate along with the private key.